# Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'owl-carousel'

Tags: angular

I used the owl-carousel in my angular 7 project.
In First add this in app.module.ts:

```
  import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
  import {OwlModule} from "ngx-owl-carousel";

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [t
        ...
      ],
      imports: [
        ...
    ,SharedModule
    ,OwlModule]
 })
```

Then I used from Component from shared folder
[image]
like this:

```
<owl-carousel  [options]="MbannerCarouselOptions" [items]="images" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding']" >
  <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of mySlideImages;let i = index">
   <div>
     <img src={{image}}/>
   </div>
  </div>

 </owl-carousel>
```

But I have error:

> Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of
>   'owl-carousel'.
>   1. If 'owl-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'options' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'owl-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("][options]="MbannerCarouselOptions" [items]="images" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'sliding']" >

Also I declareed

```
mySlideImages =  ["../assets/image/slider/banner-2.jpg","../assets/image/slider/banner-1.jpg"];  
  myCarouselImages = ["../assets/image/slider/banner-2.jpg","../assets/image/slider/banner-1.jpg"];
  myCarouselOptions={items: 2,  nav: true};
  MbannerCarouselOptions ={items:1,  nav: true,lazyLoad:true,autoplay:true,autoplayTimeout:7000,autoplaySpeed:false,autoplayHoverPause:true,loop:true};
```

in banner-carousel.component.ts .

When I used this owl-carousel in app.component.html worked,
But see error in this component.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Buchi I have mentioned a solution. Kindly check if it fixes your issue too.

Comment: @PrakashM. answer solved my problem. Basically you need to put that answer on the module which uses the module which contains carousel

Answer (score 1):

From the folder structure, I see that the `BannerCarouselComponent` is present as one of the component inside the `SharedModule` but the import of `OwlModule` has been made to `AppModule`.

So remove the existing import from `AppModule` and make the import of `OwlModule` to it's immediate parent module so that the parent module recognizes the carousel component.

```
// shared.module.ts
import { OwlModule } from "ngx-owl-carousel";
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    OwlModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: it only gives me more errors

Comment: @JunaidShaikh Could you mention what error it is?

Comment: i was adding owlModule in app.module.ts and it wasn't working, then i added it in its parent instead of root, which was admin-layout.module.ts in my case and it worked.

Comment: the error was owlcarousel is not a known element..

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Angular 13:

In the module which contains your component:

```
  import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';
```

then

```
  imports: [
    ...
    CarouselModule,
  ]
```